# Can you define a minimum and maximum amount of digits to print from a digit in C?

Tags: c, formatting, printf

For example, I want to print out a maximum of 8 digits (zero's get truncated) and a minimum of 3 digits (if it's less than that it would pad with 0's). Like so:

```
int x = 3;
printf("%max/min d", x)
```

would print

```
003
```

---

```
int x = 1674;
printf("%max/min d", x)
```

would print

```
1674
```

---

and

```
int x = 840683028573;
printf("%max/min d", x)
```

would print

```
83028573
```

Can this be done?

Comment: How much do you know about the [`printf` (and family)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) formatting codes? Do you know about the field width? About the precision? Have you experimented with those? And if that's not enough, how about making a function that does it for you (possibly by truncating or padding string buffers directly)? What have you tried there? How did it work or not work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I get your point, I wasn't descriptive. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
printf("%03d", x % 100000000);
```

`%03d` tells `printf` to pad with zeros to the left until the output is at least 3 characters long.

The other part is fairly simple, you want at most 8 from the right? Just look at the remainder.

In case your input does not fit into an integer, simply replace `int` with `long long` and then replace `%03d` with `%03lld` since `lld` is the specifier for `long long int` (or just `ld` for `long int`).

All of this assumes your values are always strictly positive (in which case you could also go with `unsigned` variables where the specifier `d` is replaced by `u`). If your values are signed and you want the final output to be 8 characters long (minus included), you can simply apply a conditional statement:

```
printf("%03d", (x < 0 ? x % 10000000 : x % 100000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple function to accomplish this:
- Use `ceil` and `log` to calculate the number of digits in the number
- Use `long long int` to store value and perform arithmetic to obtain correct results
- Use proper conversion specifier `%lld` to print the value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define min_length  3
#define max_length  8

void PrintDigits(long long int x)
{
    int noOfDigits = ceil(log10(x));
    if(noOfDigits < min_length)
        printf("%03lld\n", x % 1000000);
    else if (noOfDigits > max_length)
        printf("%lld\n", x % 100000000);

}

int main()
{

   long long int x = 3;
   PrintDigits(x);
   x = 840683028573;
   PrintDigits(x);  

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
003
83028573
```